# SCSS variables - same name, different value in different media breakpoints

Tags: css, sass, gulp-sass

I am creating an SCSS grid with specific problem - I would like to use one variable name, for instance `$pad` (for padding values), but that `$pad` variable would need to be different in different media breakpoints.

Variable value is first set through out mixins that dynamically create breakpoints and set `$pad` value within them.

```
// Default value
$pad: 0;

@mixin resolution($breakpointName, someOtherValues) { 

    @if ($breakpointName == 'mobile') {
        @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {   
            $pad: 20px;

            @content; 
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media (min-width: 521px) {   
            $pad: 30px;

            @content; 
        }            
    }
}
```

When I start to write code, I would like to use it like this

```
@include resolution(mobile) {
     .test {
         padding: $pad;
     }
}
```

Here is the problem. While using libsass (NPM gulp-sass), variable `$pad` is passed as I intended and it outputs following CSS

```
// THIS IS OK - gulp-sass
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {
    .test {
        padding: 20px;
    }
}
```

But if I use latest Ruby SASS to compile CSS through NPM gulp-ruby-sass, it outputs only default value for `$pad`

```
// THIS IS WRONG - gulp-ruby-sass 
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {
    .test {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Where is the problem here? Is it my idea or is it a bug in either libsass or ruby sass?
If my idea is the problem, is there a way to achieve what I wanted somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby Sass is correct.  Your value should be 0.

LibSass has a tendency to behind in features and behavior.  It is emulating the behavior of Sass 3.3, which freely has access to global variables from within mixins/functions.  There isn't a way to do this that will work with both Sass 3.4 *and* LibSass.  The syntax you need to use to be able to access global variables is not backwards compatible.

Either drop down to Sass 3.3 (and live with the deprecated warnings) or forget about being able to use LibSass.

Your mixin will need to look like this for Sass 3.4 to work as desired:

```
@mixin resolution($breakpointName) { 

    @if ($breakpointName == 'mobile') {
        @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 520px) {   
            $pad: 20px !global;

            @content; 
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media (min-width: 521px) {   
            $pad: 30px !global;

            @content; 
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it.

It seems that libsass accepts !global, at least doesn't make a problem with it, so it will be ok with this fix.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/) is demoing a beta version of LibSass (3.1), and it appears as though it is not choking on the `!global` flag like it used to.

Comment: Works as intended in Ruby Sass 3.4.9 (Selective Steve), and it doesn't make a problem with parsing in gulp-sass v1.2.4. I have compared large SCSS file with lot's of similar mixins and the output CSS files are identical. 

This is the solution I was looking for, thanks again Cimmanon :)